# Connecting a Domain Name to Blogger (or any other service like Shopify)

Tags: dns, blogger, cname

It is known that we need to set 4 A records on the root (@) host of the domain name in order to connect it to Blogger, while the ghs.google.com is set as a CNAME record for the www host:

```
@   216.239.32.21   A (Address)
@   216.239.34.21   A (Address)
@   216.239.35.21   A (Address)
@   216.239.36.21   A (Address)
www    ghs.google.com   CNAME
```

That being said, is it possible to have an alternative setting for the domain's root host? For example what will happen if we apply CNAME flattening and set the following record for the root (@) host?

```
@   ghs.google.com   CNAME (Alias)
```

Is it  possible to URL-redirect the root host of the domain to the www host to achieve the same result?